# Why is my Glassfish3.1.2.2/MyFaces2.1.9/JSF-managed performing better than TomEE1.5+/CDI-managed?

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish, cdi, openejb

I just migrated my web app from JSF managed beans to CDI managed beans, and I specifically wanted Tomcat or TomEE Plus to be the container of choice, because of the great things I heard about 'OpenWebBeans'. After deploying, configuring, and testing the TomEE 1.5+ / CDI-managed-beans web application, Full Page Refreshes are much much slower than Glassfish 3.1.2.2 / MyFaces 2.1.9 / JSF managed beans.

With Glassfish 3.1.2.2 / MyFaces 2.1.9 / JSF managed beans, full page refreshes only take 2 to 3 seconds.

With TomEE 1.5+ / CDI-managed-beans, full page refreshes take 5 to 10 seconds, and maybe even more than that at times. :(

Can you please tell me why is that?

Yesterday, prior to deploying the TomEE 1.5+ / CDI managed beans webapplication to the production server (Windows 2003 32-bit 4GB RAM and 1TB of diskspace), I read the following, which really did not answer my/this question at all:

[glassfish v3 vs tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557679/glassfish-v3-vs-tomcat-7)

I read that PPR is better on performance than FPR, but my session timeout/management implementation involved the following:

1. LoginFilter (servlet filter)
2. the following in h:head

meta http-equiv="refresh" content="#{session.maxInactiveInterval};url=pf_viewExpired.jsf"

Is CDI more (time) expensive than JSF managed beans, or is TomEE the container of choice for CDI? I know that JBoss (or Weld) is or has the reference implementation for CDI, so it may be best to consider JBoss/Weld.

Prior to completing the task of migrating from JSF-managed bean to CDI-managed bean (as well as migrating from Glassfish to TomEE), I had issues starting CDI-managed-bean web app on Glassfish/Weld.

Please answer the following questions above, and/or advise.  Thanks.

Comment: This is not a JSF specific question.

Comment: Really? So Glassfish, Tomcat, JSF-managed-beans, and CDI-managed-beans are 'not' a JSF specific question? I really love the performance of Glassfish-MyFaces-JSF-managed-beans, but I want to migrate to CDI, as many responsible for writing the JSF spec is recommending all to migrate to CDI in preparation for JSF 2.2+, but migrating to CDI is making my 'JSF' web app 'perform' much much worse. Also, Glassfish/Weld-for-CDI is not a good experience, from what I understand.

Comment: CDI being proxied beans and JSF managed beans being plain references, it's expected that CDI beans are a little slower, but not that extreme by a long shot. Can't you do some profiling (VisualVM, JProfiler, etc) to see where most time is spent during those 10 seconds?

Comment: @ArjanTijms, thanks for that response. I am learning that there is definitely a difference in performance between CDI and JSF managed beans. I do need to do some profiling, you are the 2nd person that recommended that; never did that before, so evidently, now is the time to learn to do just that. I am in contact with a few of the OpenEJB committers, and they are advising me via email on some things like 'JSF' rendered="...", no database access in beans (which i am 'not' doing anyway), etc... I'm going to start eliminating use of JSF rendered="..." to the best of my ability.

Comment: I have already used jvisualvm on production server (since that is where the issue exists and can be duplicated), and I have been discussing this with OpenEJB committers. Discussion recently included mention of injection of BeanA into BeanB and injection of BeanB into BeanA; this is supposed to be resolved in [CDI 1.1 - JSR 346](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=346); so, I am using MyFaces CODI BeanManagerProvider to get reference to CDI beans to avoid nested CDI injections. Hopefully, this resolves this issue of mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As inidicated in the comments above, I am working with OpenEJB (TomEE) committers to resolve this issue. Personally, I feel the issue is possibly due to the following:

1. CDI managed beans defined and referenced in the app
2. Possible CDI cyclic references (which will possibly be resolved in CDI 1.1)
3. A really large CDI @SessionScoped bean, which references/injects many other CDI beans to accomplish business logic (or tasks) within the app
4. TomEE/OpenWebBeans (which is still under development)

So, the answer remains to be determined. I opened the following OpenEJB JIRA for this issue (URL below). Feel free to watch this JIRA, if interested.

[TomEE 1.5.1 SNAPSHOT (and CDI beans) running slow on my production server](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENEJB-1955)

UPDATE:

Now, TomEE/CDI-managed-beans is performing just as well as Glassfish/JSF-managed-beans on the production server, because I recently did the following:

1. replace frequently-used dynamic SQL with @entity named queries
2. added query hints to JPA createQuery() and createNamedQuery()
3. replaced frequently-used rendered="#{EL expression}" with new facelets and ui:include src="#{EL expression}", since TomEE committers advised that rendered="#{EL expression}" gets called 6 times.

So, my TomEE/CDI-managed-beans is now running on production server and I'm monitoring performance and enduser reports/experience.

Comment: most times it's a problem with the Scopes. Did you really use CDI Scpes on that beans? Or did you just remove the javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean, making them effectively treated as @Dependent for CDI and thus they get created over and over again for each EL access?

To give you some ideas: I'm serving up to 5 million page hits/day with this stack and have response times of 5 to 25 ms for average pages...